# Android: AsyncTask: Long execution time after calling onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a simple Android AsyncTask with a long background action:

```
HANDLER.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AsyncTask<Context, Integer, GameTypeAdapter>() {
                    @Override
                    protected GameTypeAdapter doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
                        return new GameTypeAdapter(contexts[0]);//Long database action
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        pbWaiter.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(GameTypeAdapter gameTypeAdapter) {
                        txtGameName.setText(settings.getGameName());

                        cmbType.setAdapter(gameTypeAdapter);
                        if (settings.getGamePlugin() != null) {
                            cmbType.setSelection(((GameTypeAdapter) cmbType.getAdapter()).getItemPosition(settings.getGamePlugin()));
                        }

                        sldJoker.setProgress(settings.getJoker());

                        pbWaiter.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, getActivity());
            }
        });
```

If the method onPostExecute is called by thread and the last line (hideWaiter) was called the execution of the UI calls are visible after 1/10 seconds (a half second in debug mode). In this time the UI hangs and the waiter animation stops.

Why the UI thread stops?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating and running an AsyncTask in a Runnable? Never seen this before. Start asynctasks from the UI thread.

Comment: try sldJoker.setProgress(settings.getJoker()); within runOnUIThread(...)
i know onPostExecute run on UI thread itself but if you are seeing a lag, this may be worth trying

Comment: @greenapps: Please show in the code: I running from a handler to go **into** the UI thread cause I am not in it.

Comment: Mmmm.. Interesting. But what is type pbWaiter?

Comment: `if the method onPostExecute is called by thread` ? What do you mean? Are you calling it? You are not supposed to call that method as it will be done by the asynctask class.